# Why does adding text to a span change its position?

Tags: html, css

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yn7VJ/). When I take out the text, the spans line up next to each other nicely. When I add text to one, it appears lower in the page.

```
<div>
    <span id="first">
    </span>
    <span id="second">
        Text
    </span>
</div>

span#first {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;    
}

span#second {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;   
}
```

Comment: Very strange issue, but I try to avoid `inline-block` wherever possible. A hacky way to fix it is to put an `&nbsp;` inside the empty span. Looks like it's got something to do with an `inline-block` element not having any content.

Comment: `vertical-align: bottom;` on the first span without content.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default value of `vertical-align` is `baseline`.  The [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS2-20080411/visudet.html#line-height) says that for `vertical-align: baseline`

> Align the baseline of the box with the baseline of the parent box. If the box doesn't have a baseline, align the bottom of the box with the parent's baseline.

An empty block has no baseline, so the bottom of the `span` lines up with the baseline of the parent `div`.  The next `span`, since it has text (and therefore a baseline), lines up the text with the baseline of the `div`.

If you set `vertical-align: top` on both `span` elements, they should line up correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding **float: left**, like

```
span#first {
    display:inline-block;        
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
span#second {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;    
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;   
}
```

See: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yn7VJ/6/)

Comment: nice - that worked too - but I'd prefer vertical-align top as the more 'intended' and meaningful solution. Always good to know of an alternative way of doing the same thing - thanks